# Heroku worker cannot write on a web folderon the same Dyno

Tags: python, heroku

I have a free dyno instance running a simple worker that creates an RSS file and upload it to PythonAnywhere (using it just like a web server for this static `rss.xml` file).

I am trying to move from PythonAnywhere to use a web `heroku-buildpack-static` on the same worker dyno but I cannot make it work. Looks like worker and web run in different folders / environments and I cannot find where it is located.

```
worker: python main.py
web: bin/boot
```

The `main.py` script writes the file to the current folder and uploads it with success to PythonAnywhere, but I cannot see where this file is written on Heroku. I tried to create a folder `/app/web` and modify this on `main.py` to write to it but also I cannot see the file created / updated, I used the Heroku console to check this. I think a worker uses a different home or instance to run but I am not sure what is this structure located. I also created a `.profile` with the following command without success:

```
chmod -R 777 /app/web
```

The app also contains a `static.json` file with the following to point the correct folder and avoid cache

```
{
  "root": "/app/web/",
  "headers": {
    "/": {
      "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like worker and web run in different folders / environments

Yes, that is exactly what is happening.

> on the same worker Dyno

In fact, you are *not* on the same dyno. Your `web` process and your `worker` process execute in isolated environments. Consider [this section of the documentation under the heading "Process types vs dynos"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model#process-types-vs-dynos):

> A **process type** is the prototype from which one or more **dynos** are instantiated. This is similar to the way a **class** is the prototype from which one or more **objects** are instantiated in object-oriented programming.

You cannot write files to your to your `web` dyno from your `worker` dyno. They are entirely isolated and do not share a filesystem.

As msche has pointed out, dyno filesystems are ephemeral. Even if you do manage to write this file, e.g. by running a web service instead of a static host that has an API endpoint to accept the file, that file will be lost every time the dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Even if you are writing the file every two minutes as you say in your comment your site will be broken for one minute every day on average. I suggest storing this data elsewhere, e.g. [as a file on Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) or in a [client-server data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).

Note that you can also [host a static site directly from Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html), which might be a good fit here.

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what I think, thanks for your help. So the final question is, there is an easy way to publish/serve to web a static file (rss.xml) generated by a worker inside Heroku? I do not want to use an external tool like S3, since I am already using PythonAnywhere, this is a simple project for personal purpose only

Comment: The last link in my answer points to Heroku's supported data store addons. Maybe you could save the feed to Redis in your worker and load it from there in your web service? But then your web service wouldn't be static. Or _do_ use S3 and [host your static site directly from there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html), avoiding your `web` process on Heroku entirely? Or combine your two services into one, building your RSS feed and serving it from one dyno?

Comment: Yes, I will combine both in only one web Dyno, in fact, it will be better, I will generate dynamically the RSS file on the get from my feed reader tool, every 10 min or so, many thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses an ephemeral file system, see this [link](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted). The heroku documentation suggests using a third party storage such as AWS S3.

Comment: I know about this, there is no problem for me since the rss.xml file is fully generated every 2 min, my problem is how to serve it to the web from heroku? If I cannot share it with the web instance, I do not know to do this. If the final solution is to host in a different place I will remain using PythonAnywhere host